# Unusual segmentation fault coming randomly cocos2dx android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using cocos2dx v3.9 with ndk 10e with android 4.4.2 .I have created a layer and on that button is present . When button is pressed layer is removed from parent and clean up is performed and other task is performed. Crash is coming when button is pressed, mostly when tapped as soon as button appears.
code on button click is:-

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playEffect("tap.wav");
  unschedule(schedule_selector(InstructionLayer::callNextButtonMethod));

  if (this->delegate != NULL) {
    delegate->clickNextButton();
  } else {
    CCLOG("Delegate null");
  }      
  this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
}
```

and my ndk crash dump is :-

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'iNet/astar_ibt_8723bs/astar-ibt-8723bs:4.4.2/KVT49L/20140925:eng/test-keys'
pid: 14096, tid: 14115, name: Thread-1145  >>> com.Sample.Test <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 6d12a000
Stack frame #00  pc 00022090  /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+176)
Stack frame #01  pc 00a57f29  /data/app-lib/com.Sample.Test-2/libcocos2dcpp.so: Routine unaligned_load at /s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.9/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/hash_bytes.cc:43
Stack frame #02  pc 00424da8  /data/app-lib/com.Sample.Test-2/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::_Hash_impl::hash(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+36): Routine std::_Hash_impl::hash(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) at /ShobhitPC/ndk/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/functional_hash.h:131
Stack frame #03  pc 00424df8  /data/app-lib/com.Sample.Test-2/libcocos2dcpp.so (std::hash<std::string>::operator()(std::string const&) const+56): Routine std::hash<std::string>::operator()(std::string const&) const at /ShobhitPC/ndk/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/basic_string.h:3084 (discriminator 2)
```

Comment: Can you show code for removeFromParentAndCleanup?

Comment: Its a function to remove self node from parent node, part of cocos2dx framework

Comment: Does it crash when you comment out all the code in for the button? If so uncomment each line and tell us which line causes the crash